# Conference ID of OnlineMeeting created via Microsoft Graph API expiring for phone dialing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using the Microsoft Graph API in our app to integrate with Microsoft Teams and create meeting links programmatically for our customers. When the Graph API returns phone information in the `audioConferencing` attribute, we also show that so customers can join the meeting via Phone Call.

The problem is that some of them reported that they are not being able to access the scheduled meetings via Phone Call, when they try to access it says the Conference ID is not valid. I tested myself creating the meetings and calling the number right away, and it worked fine. But when I try to call to access a meeting created, let's say, yesterday, it won't work. It seems like the Conference ID is expiring, although the users can still access the meeting via URL perfectly. The only docs I found talking about this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams#meeting-expiration

Even though there is no `meetingType` attribute in the API, it seems like the meeting we are creating via API have the meeting type "Meet Now", as the Conference ID is expiring in less than 4 hours. Have anybody had a similar issue in the past? How to handle this? Is it possible to set the `meetingType` to Regular or Recurring so it won't expire so fast?

Besides that, I'm also having trouble to set the start time and end time of the meetings. I'm passing `"startDateTime":"2020-09-26T14:33:30.8546353-07:00"` and `"endDateTime":"2020-09-26T15:03:30.8566356-07:00"`, but the API always returns `"startDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"` and `"endDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"`, no matter what. Could this be related? Do I need to add some specific attribute in the payload to be able to set the start and end time?

We are using the /beta API because we need the Application scopes (OnlineMeetings.Read.All). I guess the start and end time are just broken in the /beta API.

Comment: Yes, You need to set the meetingType as Regular or Recurring to avoid conference Id expiration. Regarding startTime and EndTime can you check the format of timing in API

Comment: hey @Trinetra-MSFT, thanks for the response. This meetingType is not documented in the Graph API, how do I know what to send and whether it worked or now? Could you show me an example?